# How can i get mysql_result() to work

Tags: mysql

I am new to programming, I've been trying to create a `hit_counter` for a demo site I am developing but I keep getting an error for the `MySQL_result()` function.

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function ip_exists($ip) {
  include 'include.php';
  global $user_ip;
  $query = "SELECT `ip` FROM `ip` WHERE`ip`= '$user_ip'";
  $mysql_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($mysql_run);
  if ($query_num_rows == 0) {
    return false;
  } else if ($query_num_rows >= 1) {
    return true;
  }
}

function ip_add($ip) {
  include 'include.php';
  $query = "INSERT INTO `ip` VALUES('$ip')";
  $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
}

function update_count() {
  include 'include.php';
  $query = "SELECT `hits` FROM `hit_count`";
  if ($query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    $count = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'hits');
    $count_inc = $count + 1;

    $query_update = "UPDATE ``hit_count` SET `hits`= '$count_inc'";
    $query_update_run = mysqli_query($con, $query_update);
  }
}

if (!ip_exists($user_ip)) {
  update_count();
  ip_add($user_ip);
}
```

Comment: your mixing MySQL api's.. use mysqli_result instead http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, the function didn't even turn blue, I don't know if that is important

Comment: Mention your error in the question

Comment: Why don't you use prepared statments or other means to protect your code against SQL injection?

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*()` and `mysqli_*()` functions; they belong to  different MySQL extensions and cannot be interchanged. Since the rest of your code uses `mysqli`, **make sure you don't use any `mysql_*()` function**. The old `MySQL` PHP extension (that provides the `mysql_*()` functions) has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `mysql_*()` and `mysqli_*()` functions; they belong to  different MySQL extensions and cannot be interchanged. Since the rest of your code uses `mysqli`, **make sure you don't use any `mysql_*()` function**. The old `MySQL` PHP extension (that provides the `mysql_*()` functions) has been deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.

Using MySQLi, the equivalent of `$count = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'hits')` is:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
$count = $row['hits'];
```